# Creating virtual environments within subfolders using virtualenvwrapper

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have created a virtual environment successfully with subfolders using both the `mkproject` and `mkvirtualenv` commands like so `$ mkproject python/session1`, `$ mkvirtualenv python/session1`. Naturally located in `~/workspace` and `~/.ve` directories.

But when I list them using `workon` or `lsvirtualenv` they don't show up.

Then after 3 hrs of frustration, discovered that they don't get listed if they were created in subfolders. They only get listed if they were created using a single directory like `$ mkproject session1` and `mkvirtualenv session1`. Nice of them to let us create the venvs in subfolders but not actually let us list them

Now they get listed fine.
`workon` session1
`lsvirtualenv` session1

Since I want subfolders to represent a tree of an assignment/project, how can I create venvs within subfolders like `workspace/python/session1`, `workspace/python/session2`, `workspace/julia/seesion1`, `workspace/julia/seesion2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lsvirtualenv` uses [`virtualenvwrapper_show_workon_options`](https://bitbucket.org/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper/src/f481be386e527c53bb2cc81ed965b66a93d4e792/virtualenvwrapper.sh#lines-656) which uses [`echo *`](https://bitbucket.org/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper/src/f481be386e527c53bb2cc81ed965b66a93d4e792/virtualenvwrapper.sh#lines-597) to list environments. So no, it can only list one level of directories. You can [report](https://bitbucket.org/virtualenvwrapper/virtualenvwrapper/issues?status=new&status=open) this as a feature request or even send a pull request.